# How to create button which adds new Vue-Grid-Item?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, grid, vuex

I am creating a program for my Universities Research department, the program is for the operation of an Atomic Layer Deposition system.
The program needs to be able to allow the user to set a custom 'recipe' if you will, each grid-item will have a button with 'edit' in the bottom corner, and will take you to a separate page where you can enter your system stats like zone temps, durations, cycles, etc. We have gotten the draggable grid-items working, so that we could make the system run multiple steps over and over if we wish, but here is my goal I can't seem to accomplish:

We need to be able to add a new 'step' grid-item on button click, and we need to be able to remove a grid-item as well. I have created a button 'New Tile' and I defined a function I was hoping would work, I was trying to see if I could duplicate a grid item, but when I run the program and click the button I get the error:

"[Vue warn]: Property or method "duplicate" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties."](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.%22)

Image of app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMnjs.jpg
image of JS trying to be used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgCpd.jpg

```
  <h2 style="color: #f6a821;">Steps</h2>
  <hr class="hr" />
  <grid-layout
    :layout.sync="stepsGrid"
    :col-num="8"
    :row-height="75"
    :is-draggable="true"
    :is-resizable="false"
    :is-mirrored="false"
    :vertical-compact="true"
    :margin="[50, 50]"
    :use-css-transforms="true">

<div id="duplicater"> 
   <grid-item
      :x=stepsGrid[0].x
      :y=stepsGrid[0].y
      :w=stepsGrid[0].w
      :h=stepsGrid[0].h
      :i=stepsGrid[0].i
      :isDraggable=stepsGrid[0].isDraggable>

      <div class="Panel__name">1</div>
      <div class="editButton">
        <router-link to="/Parameters-template" class="editButton">Edit</router-link></router-link>
      </div><br>
      <div class="Panel__status">Status:</div>

    </grid-item>
```

```
<div id="bottombuttons">
  <button id="resetbutton">Reset</button>

<button id="startbutton" @click="duplicate()">New Tile</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get where is declared the `duplicate` method extactly. Don't expect it to be available from a template if it's not declared in the component's methods. Try:

```
methods: {
  duplicate() {
    /* */
  }
}
```

in the same component. If it needs to be a shared among several components, put this in a mixin.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to Javascript. I am a Senior Electrical/Computer Engineering student working for our engineering research department, I am able to learn code quickly but JavaScript in particular has been giving me troubles. I think I was trying to declare my function in the wrong area, will report back if you helped solve my issue. Appreciate it

Comment: Okay, so the issue is that when I create these new grid-item elements, the x, y, w, h, and i variables need to increment each time, otherwise its trying to copy the first grid-item ( at [0] ) and it doesn't render.

Comment: If you can create and share a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) with what you want to achieve (the beginning of it at least) I'll gladly help.